Error creating bean 'routerFunctionMapping'defined in class path:org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class
I have upgraded my java springboot application versions from
java 1.8 to java21
springboot 2.1.16 to springboot 3.2.5
spring framework 6.1.6
in controller test cases i am getting issue:

Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.RouterFunctionMapping]: Factory method 'routerFunctionMapping' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.forType(java.lang.Class)" because the return value of "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.reader()" is null
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.forType(java.lang.Class)" because the return value of "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.reader()" is null
at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JacksonJsonProvider.<init>(JacksonJsonProvider.java:55)

I am not using webflux dependency
My Controller test class:
@Slf4j
@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class) 
@Import({Test.class}) 
@EnableWebMvc class ControllerTest extends TestClass {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private Service service;

@InjectMocks
private Controller controller;

private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

@BeforeAll
public static void init() {
    prepareErrorResponse();
    prepareTestData();
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Test
void testGetList() throws Exception {
    List<Place> placeList = new ArrayList<>();
    placeList.add(place);
    Mockito.when(service.getAllPlaces()).thenReturn(placeList);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/places”)).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
}

Dependencies i am using:
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    
            <exclusions> 
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
       </dependency>

Have removed webflux dependency from my pom.xml
still getting the same error

why mixing boot dependencies with framework dependencies?

removed all the above dependencies and added

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

Still not getting any success

Thumb rule: If you have a spring boot app, then add spring boot dependencies. If it's vanilla spring project, then add non-boot dependencies to it.

Spring dependencies are not the problem.  But this is - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.forType(java.lang.Class)" because the return value of "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.reader()" is null at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JacksonJsonProvider.<init>(JacksonJsonProvider.java:55)

Its a springboot application. Tried many ways but still not able to resolve this error

Using this dependency v2.15.4

com.fasterxml.jackson.core
jackson-annotations


com.fasterxml.jackson.core
jackson-core


com.fasterxml.jackson.core
jackson-databind

